# How can I simplify Jenkinsfile-based SFDX builds by using a Jenkins Shared Library?

Tags: salesforcedx, jenkins, jenkinsfile

With many CI (Continuous Integration) Jenkins builds using SFDX, we found that we were duplicating a couple of hundred lines of build file per build. We have a large number of builds, so this became painful whenever a change was needed.

So we looked around for a Jenkins Shared Library to help with this and did not find one. A Jenkins Shared Library is a mechanism to add standardized build scripting that is pulled directly from Git into each Jenkins build. The scripting can provide higher-level building blocks or offer standardized patterns for builds.

Is there an example, or better a usable, shared library that solves this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleague has built this open source Jenkins Shared Library [sfdx-jenkins-shared-library](https://claimvantage.github.io/sfdx-jenkins-shared-library/) to solve this problem specifically for SFDX builds. See his blog post [Streamlining SFDX on Jenkins](https://medium.com/@jefersonchaves/streamlining-sfdx-on-jenkins-114f4098166?sk=dfca4c5517c7dfd38f19a715d8ec6642) that provides more overview information.

As well as solving the problem of avoiding lots of boiler-plate duplication, it supports deployment/testing in parallel against multiple org configurations. This allows us to confirm that our managed packages will work for customers who have e.g. Person Accounts enabled or who have Platform Encryption turned on. In the past, we had multiple separate builds for these configurations which were painful to setup. Instead, now as well as multiple branches building from one build, we have the multiple org configurations building from one build.

Getting this to work was a non-trivial exercise - see some of the problems via this [Jenkinsfile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jenkinsfile) tag.